# Rational isotropic space stable by a real split torus

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, algebraic-number-theory

Let $G$ be a semisimple algebraic group defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $(\rho,V)$ be an irreducible $\mathbb{Q}$-representation of $G$ preserving a sympectic form $w$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Can one find a $w$-isotropic subspace $L$ of $V$, defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ and stabilized by a (one dimensional) real split torus of $G$ ?

I would appreciate any reference to similar questions.

Comment: No. Let $K=\mathbb Q(i)$, $G=SU_{2,K/ \mathbb Q}$, $\rho$ the natural 4-dimensional representation of $G$ in $R_{K/ \mathbb Q} K^2$. Then $G_{\mathbb R}$ is anisotropic, hence has no nontrivial split tori. Hence there is no $w$-isotropic subspace stabilized by a real split torus of $G$.